# Ajax delete request with java spring forbidden

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send a delete request to java spring. The problem is I always receive a 403 forbidden response message.

This is the client-side javascript code:

```
$(".deleteList").click(function(){
        var url = "boodschappenlijstjes.htm/" + this.id;
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax(url, {
            method: "DELETE",
            success: function(){
                console.log("gelukt");
            }
        });
    });
```

The controller method I'm trying to access:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/boodschappenlijstjes/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity verwijderLijstje(Principal principal, @PathVariable(value="id") int id)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

I'm also using spring security:

```
    <http auto-config = "true">
        <intercept-url pattern='/overzicht*' access='ROLE_USER' />
        <intercept-url pattern='/klant*' access='ROLE_USER' />
        <intercept-url pattern='/boodschappenlijstjes*' access='ROLE_USER' />
        <form-login login-page="/login.htm"
                    default-target-url="/overzicht.htm" 
                    authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.htm" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" />
    </http>
```

I hope someone can help me...

Thx

Comment: Wouldn't `<intercept-url pattern='/boodschappenlijstjes*' access='ROLE_USER' />` intercept the request?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "DELETE",
        success: function(){
            console.log("gelukt");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I had to change the url in the javascript file to this:

```
"boodschappenlijstjes/" + this.id + ".htm"
```